# Defining double exclamation?

Tags: c++, boolean, logical-operators

I understand what a double exclamation mark does (or I think I understand) but I am not sure how it is defined on a random object. For example in the code snippet below:

```
Assignment *a;
if (!getAssignment(query, a))
   return false;
hasSolution = !!a;

if (!a)
   return true;
```

How do I know what value will the double exclamation mark result in ? In other words does it always convert to true ? false ? or can you define a behavior for it such as executing a method to determine the result (how does the object know how to act in this situation) ? I am bit confused about this piece of code due to all these exclamation stuff going on.. Any explanation is appreciated.

Hope I was clear and thanks.

Comment: `!!` in C++ is an anti-pattern, that’s all.

Comment: @Konrad : I disagree -- it's not an anti-pattern, it's a pattern that allows for overloading only `operator!` instead of both `operator!` and `operator bool` (or some safe-bool idiom).

Comment: @ildjarn How does that make it not an anti-pattern? *Do* overload a boolean operator when it makes sense. And when it doesn’t, don’t overload `operator!` either. They come in pairs. Exclusively.

Comment: @Konrad : Only for the few who know how to _properly_ implement the safe-bool idiom. ;-] Not everyone is an expert, and `!!` is not unreadable or confusing.

Comment: @ildjarn I find it both, and if you are incapable of implementing a boolean operator (especially in C++11, but even before) you should keep your fingers off operator overloading completely. Ignorance of established idioms is no excuse to write or condone crap code, sorry.

Comment: @Konrad : You say anti-pattern, I say idiom of its own. Your dislike of `!!` does not make it "crap". Want to avoid a C4305 warning in VC++? You can use `static_cast` or `!!` -- which is easier to type and read?

Comment: @ildjarn You should use self-explanatory code. Neither a cast nor `!!` does this. Compare explicitly instead of using implicit coercion (which, in the last consequence, is weak typing). Use `a != nullptr`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`a` is a pointer. In C++, `nullptr` is defined to be an invalid pointer. `!pointer` turns a `nullptr` pointer into `true` and a non `nullptr` pointer into `false`. `!boolean` turns `true` into `false` and `false` into `true`. It will always work.

`!(!a)` is a useful way to think of it.

Comment: I have changed the 0 into NULL to avoid some common confusion that a NULL pointer must have binary value 0 (it does not, a 0 integer constant is implicitly convertible to a NULL pointer, but there is no guarantee on the representation of NULL)

Comment: NULL is NOT defined to be an invalid pointer, it is defined be false in logical context. a = NULL; is perfectly legal. The easiest way to remember !!a is to narrow a!=0 to 1 and a==0 to 0.

Comment: Using 0 for the canonical invalid pointer is legal in C++ and historically used as the standard. NULL is an artifact from C that is only supported as part of C standard library compatibility. [It was not recommended to use NULL within C++](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#null). To avoid an unnecessary argument, I'll switch it to `nullptr` which is a keyword in C++11.

Answer (score 11):

Don't think of it as "double exclamation mark", think of it as two separate operators, one running on the result of the other.

For all primitive types, it will "work".  `!a` is equivalent to `a == 0`, so `!!a` is equivalent to `!(a == 0)`, which in turn is equivalent to `a != 0`.

For user-defined types, it won't compile unless they overload `operator !`.  But obviously, in this case, the behaviour could be almost anything.

Answer (score 5):

`!!` is not a single token in C++ and simply resolves to applying the `!` operator twice.

As `a` is a pointer and not an object of class type the `!` cannot be overloaded. It is defined to return `true` if `a` is a null pointer and `false` otherwise.

The second application of `!` simply negates the result of the first `!`.

The expression `!!a` is equivalent to `a != 0`.

Answer (score 5):

The code is horribly complicated. In reality, you want to test whether the `getAssigment` method is successful and whether the assigned pointer is non-null.

The code tests that, albeit in a convoluted fashion, taking advantage of weak typing, rather than trying to embrace explicitness and C++’ strong typing. As a consequence, it’s not idiomatic C++ and rather harder to understand than necessary.

In particular, don’t use `!!a` in C++. This is an established idiom in weakly-typed languages such as JavaScript to coerce a value into a boolean type. But in C++, this is *not* commonly used.

It’s not clear what the code does since `hasSolution` isn’t defined or used. However, I *suspect* that the code is supposed to be equivalent to the following:

```
Assignment *a;
return getAssignment(query, a) and a == nullptr;
```

(Before C++11, you need to write `0` instead of `nullptr`.)

However, this code still reveals a bad design: why is `a` passed by reference? Why isn’t it the return value? Worse, `a` is never used, so unnecessary. If `a` is indeed unnecessary, it should be left out completely. If it’s necessary, it should be the return value. In other words, the prototype of `getAssignment` should be as follows:

```
Assignment* getAssignment(the_type_of_query query);
```

And it should be used simply as follows:

```
Assignment* a = getAssignment(query);
```

Furthermore, I suspect that this code actually assigns memory ownership to the raw pointer `a`. This is [strongly discouraged](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf) in modern C++. Either use no pointers or a smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = true; 
result = !!result; // result = true, e.g. !result is false, !!result is !false.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "!!" operator, so in fact, the statement is equivalent to:

hasSolution = !(!a);

So first, operator!() is called on expression "a", then another operator!() is called on the result. In the case of our code, "a" is a pointer to Assignement. C++ defines a special case for using operator!() on a pointer type: it returns a bool which is true if the pointer is null and false otherwise. In short, the same as the expression (a == 0). Calling operator!() on the result of (!a), which is a bool, simply reverts the result, i.e. returns true if (!a) is false and false if (!a) is true.

So in conclusion, (!!a) return the same result as (a != 0). This is because "a" is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remember double-negation !!a is to narrow a!=0 to 1 and a==0 to 0. 
Which is in boolean context (i.e. C++) true or false.